# word-wrap for select control not working in Firefox but working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-select

Below code for the select control which has select option. Code is working in Chrome. It should be in multiline for selected value but when same check with Firefox it doesn't break the lines.

*Chrome is working perfect*

[image]

*Firefox doesn't work*

[image]

```css
select {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 150px">
  <select name="question" id="question">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="What was your childhood nickname?">
      What was your childhood nickname?
    </option>
    <option value="In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?">
      In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?
    </option>
    <option value="What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?">
      What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?
    </option>
    <option value="What street did you live on in third grade?">
      What street did you live on in third grade?
    </option>
    <option
      value="What is your oldest sibling's birthday month and year? (Please use this format: January 1900)"
    >
      What is your oldest sibling's birthday month and year? (Please use this
      format: January 1900)
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: [Styling a `select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS) is known to be inconsistent across the browsers. In mobile environments it's almost impossible.

Comment: is there any work around for this?

Comment: Would you please read the linked MDN article ...

Comment: I have been gone through article could not find any declaration for wrap is not supported

Comment: Aren't the evidences in your post? Again: "_The <select> element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS_" (MDN) and "_Styling a select element is known to be inconsistent across the browsers_" (me). You can waste your time by searching a workaround, or use it productively by searching a library or by building your own drop-down, if it's that important to style a `select` element consistently across the browsers. If searching  workarounds, at the end of the day you will hit your head to the mobile environments in any case, but it's your decision ...

Comment: Hi @Teemu this is not for the mobile its for the web version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225813/discussion-between-gautam-parmar-and-teemu).